# No viable overloaded '=' error even when I overloaded the assignment

Tags: c++, error-handling, operator-overloading, overloading, assignment-operator

Almost the exact questions have been asked but I do not think mine is very similar. I will explain below the code:

```
class Person{
public:
    string name;
    int age, height, weight;

    Person(string name = "empty", int age = 0, int height = 0, int weight = 0) {
        this->name = name;
        this->age = age;
        this->height = height;
        this->weight = weight;
    }
    void operator = (const Person &P){
        name = P.name;
        age = P.age;
        height = P.height;
        weight = P.weight;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Person& p);
};

class Stack{
public:
    int top;
    Person* A;
    int size;

    Stack(int s){
        top = -1;
        size = s;
        A = new Person[size];
    }

    bool isEmpty(){
        if(top == -1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    bool isFull(){
        if(top >= size-1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    void Push(Person* P){
        if(isFull()){
            cout << "No Space on Stack" << endl;
            return;
        }
        top++;
        A[top] = P;
    }
};
```

On the line `A[top] = P;` towards the bottom of the code I am getting the error `No viable overloaded '='.`

I don't understand why this is not working. I wrote the overload function for the assignment in the Person class, and I managed to overload `<<` properly earlier. I am new to C++ and overloading is a very new concept but I cannot figure out why this error is being thrown.

How to fix it?

Comment: You are passing pointer to person while calling the assignment, while the overload excepts a Person const &.

Comment: `A[top] = P;` needs to be  `A[top] = *P;`

Comment: BTW, the canonical interface is `Person& operator = (const Person &P);`

Comment: @sajas and @R Sahu thank you so much guys. I am very new to C++ and literally learned overloading earlier today. I knew it was something similar but could not figure out what was wrong. It makes sense to me now. I really appreciate the answers!

Comment: @RSahu I tried writing that originally but it was telling "Functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded" did not understand what that meant.

Comment: your `operator = ` returns `void`. That's why it's throwing that error. Change that to `Person operator=(const Person &p)` and add `return *this;` from the function

Comment: @SaileshD I don't agree because there are no point in the posted code that tries to use result value of a `=` operator.

Comment: @Fall0ut, that means, you may not have `void operator = (const Person &P)` and `Person& operator = (const Person &P)`.

Answer (score 0):

You defined only `operator =` that takes (reference to) `Person`, but you tried to assign a pointer `Person*`. Operator to do such thing isn't defined, so you got the error.

To fix, there are some options depending on the expected usage.

- dereference the pointer before assigning
- change the argument of `Push` to copy or reference of `Person`, not a pointer
- Add `operator =` that takes `Person *` to `class Person`